# Python - unittest trying to call imported custom argparser

Tags: python, argparse, python-unittest

I have a unittest that wants to call an imported module to do both `parse_os` based on the unittest's command-line option but it seems unittest does not recognize the option, any ideas:

```
./python testParser.py --mac
option --mac not recognized
Usage: testParser.py [options] [test] [...]

Options:
  -h, --help       Show this message
  -v, --verbose    Verbose output
  -q, --quiet      Minimal output
  -f, --failfast   Stop on first failure
  -c, --catch      Catch control-C and display results
  -b, --buffer     Buffer stdout and stderr during test runs

Examples:
 testParser.py                               - run default set of tests
 testParser.py MyTestSuite                   - run suite 'MyTestSuite'
 testParser.py MyTestCase.testSomething      - run MyTestCase.testSomething
 testParser.py MyTestCase                    - run all 'test*' test methods
                                           in MyTestCase
```

I want to run my unittest program like this: `python testParser.py --mac`

EDITTED: Works now by changing 'unittest.main()' to:

```
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=stderr_file)
itersuite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TT28046_ForensicSearchSmokeTest)
runner.run(itersuite)
```

Unittest program:

```
import logging
import unittest

from myargparse import *

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

   def test_parse_os(self):
        ## Parse the args:
       self.install = install_sw(parse_os(arg=""))
       print 'Which os? %s' % self.install

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    # get the default logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    # add a file handler
    logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('stdout.txt', mode='w'))
    # set up a stream for all stderr output
    stderr_file = open('stderr.txt', 'w')
    # attach that stream to the testRunner
    unittest.main(testRunner=unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=stderr_file))
```

My imported module:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys

def parse_os(arg):
    my_os = ''
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--mac",
                    action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("-w", "--win",
                    action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.mac:
       print 'Mac'
       my_os = "Mac"
    if args.win:
       print 'Windows'
       my_os = "Windows"
    return my_os

def install_sw(my_os):
    installed_os = None
    if my_os == 'Mac':
        print 'Installing Mac...'
        installed_os = 'Mac'
    if my_os == 'Windows':
        print 'Installing Windows...'
        installed_os = 'Windows'
    return installed_os
```

Comment: You can't *and you shouldn't*. `sys.argv` is a simple list so you *can* change its contents/replace it.

Answer (score 3):

The `sys.argv` variable is a simple `list` so you can modify/replace it at your wish.
I'd consider using a context manager in this case, on the lines of:

```
class SysArgv(object):
    def __init__(self, argv):
        self._old_argv = sys.argv
        sys.argv = argv
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        sys.argv = self._old_argv
        return False
```

And used as:

```
In [4]: with SysArgv(['a', 'b', 'c']):
   ...:     print(sys.argv)
   ...:     
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

In your case simple wrap the test code like:

```
with SysArgv(['the_module_name.py', '--mac']):
    # test code goes here
```

and the `argparse` module will see the arguments you wants.

As for passing the arguments to the unittest module when running the tests, it's possible passing the `argv` argument to `unittest.main`. From the documentation:

```
The `argv` argument can be a list of options passed to the program, with the first element being the program name. If not specified or `None`, the values of `sys.argv` are used.
```

However in this case you should modify the `sys.argv` variable before calling `unittest.main`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = ['name_of_module.py'] + sys.argv[-1:]   # last argument as option for the test
    with SysArgv(sys.argv[:-1]):   # or modify how you want
        unittest.main(argv=options)
```

Comment: Does this also work with `--keyword value` arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using just '-m' instead of '--mac'?

You may also try:

```
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-m", "--mac",
              dest="mac",
              action="store_true",
              help="Run as Mac")
parser.add_option("-w", "--win",
              dest="win",
              action="store_true",
              help="Run as Win")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: You misinterpreted the question. The problem is *not* the parser. Is that he's calling `unittest.main` which looks at `sys.argv` and raises an exception because it doesn't recognize that option. The exception is raised well before the test is run.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions but I decided to go with this to limit the changes to my program.

Instead of calling 'unittest.main()', I just changed to call the following:

```
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=stderr_file)
itersuite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTest)
runner.run(itersuite)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the answers here, I originally did this simple hack, and it worked:

```
# Change sys.argv before unittest tries to parse our args
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]  # Replace with only the first arg
unittest.main()
```

The I realized I could still use all the unitest command line args, and in my case I was just passing a bunch of paths, so anything starting with a "-" could just be passed on and there is no need to hack anything since `unittest.main()` has an `argv` argument

```
# Pass on options, and more importantly, don't pass on ALL args
options = [sys.argv[0]] + [a for a in sys.argv if a.startswith("-")]
unittest.main(argv=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out all argparse and not arparse parameters and send then ones not being argparse arguments to sys.argv which is the one unittest uses:

```
args, notknownargs = parser.parse_known_args()
sys.argv[1:] = notknownargs
```